# AutoMapper generates exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework, automapper-6

I am using AutoMapper 6.0.2 in a .NET EF project and I can't seem to get AutoMapper to work.

In a tutorial that was using AutoMapper 4.x.x this was used:

```
class A
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
    B test {get; set;}
}

class B
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
    C test{ get; set;}
}

class C
{
    string Name;
}

Mapper.CreateMap<C, CDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<B, BDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<A, ADto>();

return entities.Select(Mapper.Map<A, ADto>);
```

I have tried below but I always get exceptions later when I use Mapper.Map.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<C, CDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<B, BDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<A, ADto>();
});
```

and

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<C, CDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<B, BDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<A, ADto>();
});
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

My misstake. I had another class that I forgot to inlcude in the MapperConfiguration. When I added the class I got it working.